# Batch file need info

Tags: batch-file, editing

I am combining multiple Batch files I made into 1 Batch file.
I have a few questions.
I am going through thousands of pictures and when I come across 1 that I need I copy it to my documents to review later, that's what the "copy" in the script is for. I have it set up to loop so I can just keep entering files to send to my documents. 
First. I would like to be able to jump back to the menu when I type Menu, so it would leave the loop and goto :MENU.
Second. I have no idea if this is possible... but going through so many pictures that I would like to be able to save where I left off. Thats where the GOTO :Set comes in to play. I would like to be able to type in the number of the picture and have the Batch file save it, so that when I enter GOTO :OPEN it will then open the picture I left off on.

Sorry if this sounds confusing, any help would be great. If you have any questions feel free to ask
Thank you

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO Welcome to the sub-menu
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Rename files in folder.
ECHO 2 - Copy files to My Documents.
ECHO 3 - Set file to you left off on.
ECHO 4 - Open file you left off on.
ECHO 5 - Exit.
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO Rename
IF %M%==2 GOTO COPY
IF %M%==3 GOTO SET
IF %M%==4 GOTO OPEN

:Rename
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
set /a i+=1
ren "%%a" "!i!.new"
)
ren *.new *.jpg
GOTO MENU

:COPY
cls
SET /P filename=Enter the file which should be moved:
xcopy %filename%.* C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents
if not exist %filename%.* goto :Failure
if exist %filename%.* goto :data
GOTO MENU

:SET

GOTO MENU

:OPEN

GOTO Me

:Failure
echo Failure
pause
goto :COPY

:data
timeout /t 3

goto :COPY
```

Comment: I think you will want to use something like the following: http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/getini.txt

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out another way to leave the loop, now I just need to enter anything that does not match a name in the folder.
This is what I have now and is working Great.

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO Welcome to the sub-menu
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Rename files in folder.
ECHO 2 - Copy files to My Documents.
ECHO 3 - Set file to you left off on.
ECHO 4 - Open file you left off on.
ECHO 5 - Exit.
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO Rename
IF %M%==2 GOTO COPY
IF %M%==3 GOTO SET
IF %M%==4 GOTO OPEN

:Rename
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p i=Enter Starting Number:
for %%a in (*.JPG) do (
    set /a i+=1
    ren "%%a" "!i!.new"
)
ren *.new *.JPG
GOTO MENU

:COPY
cls
SET /P filename=Enter the file which should be moved:
xcopy %filename%.* C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents
if not exist %filename%.* goto :Failure
if exist %filename%.* goto :data

:Failure
goto :menu

:data
timeout /t 3

goto :copy
GOTO MENU

:SET
cls
del temp.txt
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
echo Your input was: %INPUT%
pause
echo %INPUT%.JPG  >>temp.txt
GOTO MENU

:OPEN
set /p texte=< temp.txt  
  echo %texte%
  pause
 set q=%texte%
 start %texte%
GOTO menu

:Failure
echo Failure
pause
goto :COPY

:data
timeout /t 3

goto :COPY
```